# Bitbucket pipelines Buffers some files but it doesn't upload

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

So I have setup on my bitbucket a pipeline to push to my demo server

```
image: php:7.1.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
        - composer
        script:
           - echo "Pipeline Init"
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
           - echo "Initiating Push site:Source."
           - git config git-ftp.syncroot wordpress/wp-content/themes/ip-callcenters/
           - git ftp init --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://myip/ipcc/wp-content/themes/myfolder/
```

So far everything works..

Tells me `There are 143 files to sync:`

and starts `[1 of 143] Buffered for upload` etc etc...

So for some reason stops buffering after 26-30 files being buffered it doesn't continue, then says Uploading.... and after some minutes I get a

```
fatal error: Could not upload files., exiting...
```

Any idea how can I get this working ?

Answer (score -1):

```js
- git ftp push --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASSW ftp://myip/ipcc/wp-content/themes/myfolder/
```

use `"ftp push"` when you sync repository.
and `"ftp init"` when you clone repository to FTP for first time.